# Is there a way to configure different 'retries' for tasks in the same DAG

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG with many sub-tasks in it. In the middle of the DAG, there is a validation task and based on the result/return code from the task, i want to take two different paths. If success, one route(a sequence of tasks) will be followed and in case of failure, we would like to execute a different set of tasks. There are two problems with the current approach, one is that, validation tasks execute many times(as per the retries configured) if the exit code is 1. Second there is no way possible to take different branches of execution

To solve problem number 1, we can use the retry number is available from the task instance, which is available via the macro {{ task_instance }} . Appreciate if someone could point us to a cleaner approach, and the problem number 2 of taking different paths remains unsolved.

Answer (score 20):

You can have `retries` at the task level.

```py
run_this = BashOperator(
    task_id='run_after_loop',
    bash_command='echo 1',
    retries=3,
    dag=dag,
)

run_this_last = DummyOperator(
    task_id='run_this_last',
    retries=1,
    dag=dag,
)
```

Regarding your 2nd problem, there is a concept of [Branching](https://airflow.apache.org/1.10.3/concepts.html#branching).

[image]

> The [BranchPythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/1.10.3/_api/airflow/operators/python_operator/index.html#airflow.operators.python_operator.BranchPythonOperator) is much like the [PythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/1.10.3/_api/airflow/operators/python_operator/index.html#airflow.operators.python_operator.PythonOperator) except that it expects a `python_callable` that returns a task_id (or list of task_ids). The task_id returned is followed, and all of the other paths are skipped. The task_id returned by the Python function has to be referencing a task directly downstream from the `BranchPythonOperator` task.

Example DAG:

```py
import random

import airflow
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='example_branch_operator',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval="@daily",
)

run_this_first = DummyOperator(
    task_id='run_this_first',
    dag=dag,
)

options = ['branch_a', 'branch_b', 'branch_c', 'branch_d']

branching = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='branching',
    python_callable=lambda: random.choice(options),
    dag=dag,
)
run_this_first >> branching

join = DummyOperator(
    task_id='join',
    trigger_rule='one_success',
    dag=dag,
)

for option in options:
    t = DummyOperator(
        task_id=option,
        dag=dag,
    )

    dummy_follow = DummyOperator(
        task_id='follow_' + option,
        dag=dag,
    )

    branching >> t >> dummy_follow >> join
```

Comment: This works for BashOperator but not other operator (eg. DataprocSubmitJobOperator)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first problem, you set task/Operator specific retry options quite easily. Reference: [baseoperator.py#L77](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L77).

Problem two, you can branch within a DAG easily with `BranchPythonOperator` (Example Usage: [example_branch_operator.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_branch_operator.py)). You will want to nest your validation task/logic within the `BranchPythonOperator` (You can define and execute operators within operators).