# Set different retry delay times for tasks within the same dag

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I have a `airflow` dag with many sub-tasks, I know when certain tasks fail they can be re-run in 5 minutes, while other tasks can be re-run in 60 minutes. How can I set my tasks to rerun on failure as such?

I found this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55948332/is-there-a-way-to-configure-different-retries-for-tasks-in-the-same-dag) on stack overflow however this only changes the number of retries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to configure different 'retries' for tasks in the same DAG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55948332/is-there-a-way-to-configure-different-retries-for-tasks-in-the-same-dag)

Comment: @Kermit it's close that's setting different number or retries, I'd like to change how long it waits before a retry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operators should support a `retry_delay` as well - see [BaseOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/index.html#package-contents):

> retry_delay (datetime.timedelta) – delay between retries

Comment: Thanks was looking at the `PythonOperator` docs which didn't have these listed